# How to make image expand/shrink to available space while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do we make an image "fit" inside the second column below? This is Bootstrap 4 and I want the right column to take the same height as the left column and then the image to fit inside it while keeping the aspect ratio. I also want it to be centered horizontally and vertically.

[image]

The HTML currently looks like this:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- Upload Image option -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- Image URL option -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="leg.jpg" height="70px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I simply don't want to specify that `height="70px"` attribute. The image should expand/shrink to cover the available height (dictated by the left column). Width of the image should then adjust to keep aspect ratio intact. The image should finally be centered horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the screenshot there's CSS from other classes and more HTML layout than what's provided. Here are the following styles relevant to the img with a `<figure>` wrapped around it.

> ```
> <figure class='figure'> <img class='figure-img fluid-img'...> </figure>
>
>  img {
>    object-fit:contain; 
>    max-width:100%; 
>    height:auto
>  }
>  .col {
>    display:flex; 
>    flex-flow:column nowrap; 
>    justify-content: center;
>    align-items:center
>  }
> ```

```css
.form-row {
  max-width: 540px;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<main class='container'>
  <section class="form-row">

    <section class="column col-8">
      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <input type="radio">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input form-control">
            <label class="custom-file-label">Choose file</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <input type="radio">
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="url" class="custom-url-input form-control">

      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="column col-4">
      <figure class='figure'>
        <img src="https://oehawkseye.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/chicken-leg.png" class='figure-img img-fluid'>
      </figure>
    </section>

  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Unfortunately in your example, it's the right column that is dictating the height, which is exactly what I don't want.As I said, the image should resize to fit within the height provided by the row and the width of the image should then change to keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: I guessed as to how row's height is determined by using layout and classes that produce the styles and layout of the screenshot provided. If you were to provide the real code I could probably post a more solid answer. Each column is 50% and the img is auto height so the width of the img is actually the determining factor of img height. If the right column is 33% and left 67% the img should shrink.

Comment: @dotNET Nevermind the update looks about right, please review at your convenience.